# Заблокировать клавишу, но получить ее код c#

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi

Можно как-нибудь заблокировать клавишу Win, но все также получать код этого символа.

Если блокирую клавишу с помощью WinAPI, то событие не перехватывает нажатие клавиши, но это необходимо.

```
  private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProcDelegate(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
    private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;//Keyboard hook;
    private static IntPtr m_hHook;
    private static LowLevelKeyboardProcDelegate m_callback;

    //Keys data structure
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT
    {
        public Keys key;
    }

    //Установка перехвата клавиатуры
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelKeyboardProcDelegate lpfn, IntPtr hMod, int dwThreadId);

    //Разблокировка клавиатуры
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

    //Hook handle
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(IntPtr lpModuleName);

    //Вызов следующего хука
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    //Захват <WinKey> 
    public static IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardHookProc_win(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0)
        {
            KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT objKeyInfo =
             (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT));
            if (objKeyInfo.key == Keys.RWin ||
                objKeyInfo.key == Keys.LWin)
            {
                return (IntPtr)1;//<WinKey> 
            }
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(m_hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
```

Можно как-нибудь заблокировать клавишу, но получать событие от нажатия этой клавиши.

**UPD**

```
m_callback = LowLevelKeyboardHookProc_win; 
m_hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, m_callback, 
 GetModuleHandle(IntPtr.Zero), 0);
```

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, у вас же вызывается метод `LowLevelKeyboardHookProc_win`, правильно? Чем вам не событие нажатия клавиши?

Comment: @VladD, Это событие не срабатывает при нажатии клавиши. Оно указывает, какую клавишу надо заблокировать. А у меня есть окно WPF, которое реагирует на нажатие, так если я заблокирую клавишу Win, то событие  просто не реагирует. А необходимо, что бы клавиша не вызывала в ОС никаких действий, но то чтобы сработало событие, что клавиша была нажата.

Comment: Эээ? «Указывает, какую клавишу надо заблокировать»? Не, чё-то не то, то есть он, по-вашему, не вызывается, а каким-то магическим образом оказывает влияние?

Comment: @VladD, в UPD написал, как блокирую. Клавиша блокируется при запуске

Comment: Ну, в вашем коде лишь установка хука, который будет вызываться на нажатии клавиши. Это не блокировка клавиши (такой функциональности нигде нет), это такая подписка на все нажатия как бы. Так что пока проблем не вижу.

Comment: @VladD, хук устанавливается, дальше события KeyUp, KeyDown не приходят. Что бы они пришли нужно вызывать UnhookWindowsHookEx

Comment: Но ваш хук-то вызывается?

Comment: @VladD, Хук вызывается единожды, когда я вызову SetWindowsHookEx. После клавиша блокируется, не работает и не реагирует на событие KeyDown